# How to unzip opencv in raspberry pi?

Tags: opencv, ocr, raspberry-pi3

I downloaded the opencv 3.3.0 in my raspberry pi by command prompt. I want to unzip that file by command prompt

Comment: what you have tried so far that also post so that it would be easy to get your expectation for contributor.

Answer (score 0):

unzip opencv.zip should do the job. You can also follow the instructions [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/) for a smoother installation.